Как мне записать эти данные в sqlite
у меня такая проблема. Я сделал процесс регистрации, где пользователь вводит данные переходя из одного состояния к другому, но теперь как мне записать все эти данные в sqlite после нажатия на кнопку завершить регистрацию, при этом использую sqlachemy
И где написано user и No в бд должны подставится данные которые ввёл пользователь
Мой бот написан на aiogram, вот его код
@user.message(F.text == "Изменить учётные данные")
async def register(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await set_user(message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(Registry.name)
    await message.answer("Введите ваше имя")


@user.message(Registry.name)
async def register_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext): # Здесь мы ловим состояние
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Registry.surname) # Здесь мы устанавливаем состояние для того, чтобы принять возраст человека
    await message.answer("Отлично, теперь введите вашу фамилию")# Здесь мы выводим сообщение для того, чтобы пользователь знал какие данные ему надо вводить в бота


@user.message(Registry.surname)
async def register_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(surname=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Registry.patronymic)
    await message.answer("Отлично, теперь введите ваше отчество")

@user.message(Registry.patronymic)
async def register_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(patronymic=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Registry.department)
    await message.answer("Хорошо, теперь введите ваш отдел")

@user.message(Registry.department)
async def register_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(department=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Registry.office)
    await message.answer("Хорошо, теперь введите ваш кабинет")

@user.message(Registry.office)
async def register_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(office=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data() # Здесь мы вытаскиваем все наши данные, а именно имя, возраст, номер телефона пользоватея
    await message.answer(f"Ваше имя: {data["name"]}\n\nВаша фамилия: {data["surname"]}\n\nВаше отчество: {data["patronymic"]}"
                         f"\n\nВаш отдел: {data["department"]}\n\nВаш кабинет: {data["office"]}\n\nВсё верно?",
                         reply_markup=kb.YESandNOregistry)
    await state.clear()


@user.message(F.text == "Да, завершить регистрацию ✅")
async def registry_Yes(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("В разработке...", reply_markup=kb.home)


А где ошибки или проблемы? Собственно, пишете логику добавления на sqlalchemy или напрямую на SQL. За Вас этого делать никто не будет, а лишь могут помочь решить конкретную проблему, которую Вам не удалось. С такой простой задачей вполне справится и chatGPT.
